# Выходит ошибка при unit test в angular 2, Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?)

Tags: юнит-тесты, angular2, jasmine, karma

```
  import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
  ...

 fdescribe('WidgetAdditionalPricesComponent', () => {
   let component: WidgetAdditionalPricesComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<WidgetAdditionalPricesComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [ChainService, Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions],
  declarations: [WidgetAdditionalPricesComponent, WidgetToolbarComponent, MaxLengthPipe, DropdownComponent, DatexPipe],
  imports: [HttpModule]
})
  .compileComponents();
 }));

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WidgetAdditionalPricesComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('test color of zavods', () => {
    let color = component.getColorName('ОНПЗ');
    expect(color).toBe('blue');
  });
});
```

Выходит следующая ошибка: Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?).
Что сделать? Вроде добавил RequestOptions. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указали "RequestOptions" в поле "providers" в то время, как этот класс не является сервисом(Injectable), а просто утилитарным классом для взаимодействия с Http сервисом. Если убрать его из декларации тест-модуля, то должно заработать